# Reload Image Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to change src of image using jquery but my code does not work.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgCaptcha").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Account/CaptchaImage",
                success: function (result) {
                    var img_src = $(this).attr('src');
                    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                    $(this).attr('src', img_src + '?' + timestamp);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

### **Edit**

I edited my code, but still not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imgCaptcha").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/CaptchaImage",
            success: function (result) {
                var img_src = result;
                var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                $("imgCaptcha").attr('src', img_src + '?' + timestamp);
            }
        });
    });
```

});

### **Final Answer**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgCaptcha").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Account/CaptchaImage",
                type: "post",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#imgCaptcha").attr("src", "/Account/CaptchaImage/?r=" + Math.random());
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `var img_src = $(this).attr('src');` >> the `this` is referring to the ajax call, not yout imgCaptcha

Comment: @juvian is right, check my answer below for a fix to your problem

Answer (score 0):

you're in a closure, so the `$(this)` you're refering to isn't the one you think, you should keep it in a variable to access it later :

```
    $("#imgCaptcha").click(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/CaptchaImage",
            success: function (result) {
                var img_src = self.attr('src');
                var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                self.attr('src', img_src + '?' + timestamp);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgCaptcha").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Account/CaptchaImage",
                success: function (result) {
                    var img_src = $("#imgCaptcha").attr('src');
                    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                    $("#imgCaptcha").attr('src', img_src + '?' + timestamp);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to reference is, the image ID. But using `this` would reference the Ajax context. Which you don't want to. That's why its giving you error. Try the following code instead

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgCaptcha").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Account/CaptchaImage",
                success: function (result) {
                    var img_src = $('#imgCaptcha').attr('src');
                    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                    $('#imgCaptcha').attr('src', img_src + '?' + timestamp);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

If updating the code to `var img_src = result;` isn't making it work. Then please get to know that you should get the response as a plain image source. Not the image of anyother MIME type data like link_here.png (XML)

What you should get would be

```
/link/to/file.png
```

and once this is caught. You will get the image loaded and the Timestand appeneded to it.

What you should worry about would be, errors in your request. Although your code is enough to load the image. But you should always try to capture the error events too. Add this to your code

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 alert("some error");
}
```

This would let you know what the error was.

Secondly, you **should** always use the Console of the browser. To know what the request was, where it was sent and what was the response. You can access it using <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser. It would even show you the Response that was sent to you by the server.

Comment: Have a look at my answer now :)

Comment: I added error section for my ajax call but no error returned and I think ajax successfully work but my image is not refreshed.

Comment: Do you mean that I should save the returned image temporarily somewhere and then return its path? @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan

Comment: No! What I mean is that you should have something like this, `Response.Write("image_path.png");` and make sure, only the text of the image is returned, all other head and body section is removed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>

    $("#refresh").click(function () {
        var img = $('<img />', {
            id: 'CaptchaImg'

        });
        img.attr("style", "height:42px;")
        img.removeAttr("src")
        img.attr('src', '@Url.Action("ShowCaptchaImage", "Support")/' + new Date().getTime());
        $("#test").html('');
        img.appendTo('#test');

    });
</script>
```

$("#refresh").click(function () {
        var img = $('', {
            id: 'CaptchaImg'

        });
        img.attr("style", "height:42px;")
        img.removeAttr("src")
        img.attr('src', '@Url.Action("ShowCaptchaImage", "Support")/' + new Date().getTime());
        $("#test").html('');
        img.appendTo('#test');

    });